# eCommerce -> After a digital course has been purchased, should I still show this course in category page?

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I am developing an online course website based on WordPress.

Website has 30 courses in total.

Courses are divided into 5 categories (A, B, C, D, E).

There are 6 courses per category.

Each course also has a fixed price.

So once a user purchase a course,
user can only purchase it once because it`s a digital course.

In addition, course status can be either "not started", "in progress" or "done".

Therefore, users can access their "membership area" and
see courses divided into the following 3 sections based on user activity:

- "Not started" section shows all courses that user did not start yet.
- "In progress" section shows all courses that are in progress.
- "Done" section shows all courses that user already completed.

**Here is my question:**

Once user purchase a course,
should I continue showing this course in categories page OR
should I remove this course from categories page?

For example,
Category A has 6 courses.
User just purchased 5 courses in this category.
Should category A page show all 6 courses with 5 of them tagged as "purchased" OR
should category A page show only 1 course, the course which user did not purchase yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you should display the Purchased instead of hiding it. Maybe they want to reffer the course to someone or would like the satisfaction of seeing that they bought all the courses in any case there are no real benefits in hiding it.

For further experience somewhere inside the product page instead of the Buy course button it could have a button that says : Access Course or something similar.